# Copy a range from a column in one table to a row in another table, each time adding to last row

Tags: excel, vba, windows, transpose

```
Worksheets ("CAF_VBA").Range ("C17:C27").Copy
Worksheets ("CAF_VBA").Range ("F40").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

Above code copies a column of data C17:C27 to a row in the sheet begining F40. How do I adjust the code so that every time I click the commandbutton it copies the data to the last row instead of just F40. e.g. F40 then F41 then F42 with each click of command button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `xlUp` and `Offset`:

```
Worksheets ("CAF_VBA").Range ("F" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```